# Logging to iOS device log / Xcode Console from React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to debug a React Native app which is already published in to the AppStore and while the app has a bunch of `console.info` / `console.warn` calls — seems that no log messages reach the device log (which I access through Xcode > Device & Simulators > some device > Open Console).

Also, I've just created a test app and added a bunch of console calls there, and while I see them all in Chrome Inspector it seems that they never reach device logs.

So the question is — am I doing something wrong or the console calls are actually not logged into the device log? If so, is there any other solution to do it? Something as simple as `NSLog` preferred.

Thanks a lot